# Azure Active Directory Sync Health - "Latest data is not available"

Tags: active-directory, azure, synchronization, health

Anyone uing AD Connect Sync Health in a non-Express setup yet?

I have a the Sync Health agent installed, and connected to AAD, but am getting an error - in the Sync Error applet it shows "Latest data is not available". AD Connect itself seems fine, my objects are syncing aok.

Interestingly, the DC at the on-premise end shows no Event Log entries in the Microsoft Azure AD Sync/Debug and Sync/Operational logs - not only no errors, no entries at all. Maybe its an issue at the on-premise end?

Any suggestions welcomed, Justin

Comment: Does it work now? if not, maybe we should check your on-premise firewall settings, we should add TCP/UDP 443 and TCP/UDP 5671, more infromation about the requirements, refer to the link.https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect-health/active-directory-aadconnect-health-agent-install

Comment: Thanks Jason, missed that one. Will set the firewall rules for 5671 to the windows service bus and re-test, will advise.

Comment: OK, please let me know if you would like further assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Jason Ye's answer about the outgoing firewall port was the issue - i can see traffic in the syslog now, but could not before (not even Deny traffic). I'm thinking the health update is so infrequent my logs are rolling over before it happens.

Working now, thanks all.
Justin

Answer (score 1):

As of right now, two things can trigger this notice:

1. Need to update to the latest health agent
2. You have data freshness alerts active on the service

Update your agent (or turn on auto-update) and verify the connectivity between the agent and the service.